# G-Means: Learning K in K Means

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, k-means

I am currently trying to understand the paper ['Learning K in K-Means' by Hamerly & Elkan (2004)](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2526-learning-the-k-in-k-means.pdf), which is the paper implementing G-Means, an automated way in selecting K for K-Means. There is one formula (in particular) in the paper that I am struggling to understand, which I am hoping someone can provide some insight into here.

> ... project X onto:
>
> $v: x'_i = <x_i, v > / ||v||^2 $
>
> X' is a 1-dimensional representation of the data projected onto v.

Where X is a subset of the data, with each row representing a data-point & dimensions d.

This formula is found on page 4

I understand ||v|| is the norm of v. My main issue is understanding what $<x_i , v>$ means, and also what the output of this formula would look like.

If someone could point me to some resources that would explain this, or offer an explanation themselves it would be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if there's a typo here; that looks like the formula for a projection (and that's what the paper says it is), but in that case the denominator shouldn't be squared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the context, you're projecting $x_i$ onto the vector $v$.  If you recall projections from calculus, the projection of vector $a$ onto vector $b$ is given by $\frac{a \cdot b}{||b||}$.

This is just a weird notation for the dot, or inner product.

For reference, see this math.stackexchange post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570887/what-are-the-angle-brackets-in-linear-algebra

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the advice. What do you think is the relevance of the comment above? Where the denominator shouldnt be squared?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure.  The square in the denominator is fishy.  You might email the authors. about it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the [Rayleigh Quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient), and you can refer to this article: [The Rayleigh’s principle and the minimax principle for the
eigenvalues of a self-adjoint matrix](https://people.math.osu.edu/costin.10/5102/Rayleigh%20quotient.pdf).

[image]